# Locate a specific content view in a UITableViewController using viewWithTag function

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to locate a specific content view in a table view.
This table view is driven by a UITableViewController that is used to show my user with some parameters he can change in my app.
For one of those cell, I need to programatically add a UITextView that I had subclass (NSTextStorage) to change text attribute, have rich text editing and so. 
So I need to find that specific cell (content view) to by able to call my .addSubview. I thought this you be as simple as adding a specific tag to this view and call the .viewWithTag later in my viewDidLoad. The problem is a got a nil!?!

Here's the little code snippet and a capture of my table hierarchy

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let specific = self.view.viewWithTag(99) //--> Return nil
    let specific2 = self.tableView.viewWithTag(99) //--> Also nil
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong or did I miss something? This's my first shot at this method (viewWithTag) and maybe there's something else I need to do?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call this on `viewDidLoad`, since you are using an `UITableView`, all those Cells will be only loaded **AFTER** `viewDidLoad` on the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

So if you want to insert anything on a Cell, you must use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to do that.

I'm not sure if `viewWithTag` works with TableView, but you shouldn't do that. To get a View for a specific Cell (after it being loaded on the method I said above) you can call the method below:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];`

Comment: you forget that is a UITableViewController who is table view is quite "static" and do not use the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. There is no delegate or datasource to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search, I decided to go with a Container View.
So I place UIContainerView control inside my cell. This create a embed segue to a custom view.

[image]

In this view a can override the viewDidLoad and load my custom UITextView Control...

```
class CustomView: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ... code of my super class UITextView with my custom NSTextStorage

    self.view.addSubview(specialTextBox)
}
```

So now it works! :-)